# Class method as worker for multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am a bit lost with the understanding of the multiprocessing module of Python. As this is my first post here, I hope that my explanation is good enough even with my limited English.

Explanation:
I have a sensor system which is connected by TCP/IP. I run the reading in an infinite loop to detect if an object passed the sensor. If an object is detected the sensor process sends a signal to the main process as information that something has been detected. I use the Pipe module to transfer informations between the two processes. 
The code shown below works as expected without failures so far. I shortened the code to the minimum because my question is more general.

Question:
The 'Master()' class starts the new process. I create an instance of the 'Sensor()' class to set up the socket for the communication. After that, I am using the method 'StartDetection()' as a worker for the new process. Is this the way to do it? For some reason, I don`t feel well to create an instance the 'Sensor' class inside the 'Master()' class and then use the method as a worker.
I could also imagine defining a normal function (without a class), instancing the 'Sensor()' inside and use it as a worker (All in one).

What would be the right way to start a long-running process like this?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import socket

class Master():

    def __init__(self):
        self.mainPipe, self.processPipe = Pipe()
        self.sensor = Sensor(self.processPipe)


    def StartSensorReading(self):
        self.process = Process(target=self.sensor.StartDetection)
        self.process.start()

        # Do something else

        self.process.join()


class Sensor():

    def __init__(self, pipe):
        self.pipe = pipe
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server_address = ('192.168.1.99', 64000)
        self.sock.connect(server_address)

    def StartDetection(self):

        while True:
            message = 'SW,01,065,+000022222\r\n'.encode('ASCII')
            self.sock.send(message)
            print(self.sock.recv(100))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = Master()
    master.StartSensorReading()
```